# How to really pause a stripe subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe's php wrapper for its api to manage customers subscriptions.
We need to have a pause option for subscriptions which range in time from 3 months to a year. The pause option would be one of three options 1 month 3 months and 6 months. The method I was using was to set a trial version for their Stripe account for the duration of the pause but the problem with that is once the trial ends they are charged, albeit at a prorated amount, but thats not the type of pause we are looking for. We need it to our customers seem actually paused then when it un pauses it has the same amount of time on it left as when they paused it with no upfront charge. I have been trying to figure out how to do this but cant figure out a way to have it all happen on stripe. any of my other ideas involve having a cron job or some kind of time trigger on our server to handle the end of their pause period.
example of what I have so far:

```
pause_sub($sub_id) {
  $sub = Subscription::retrieve($sub_id);
  $sub->trial_end = time() + (31556952 / 12);
  $sub->save();
  return "Subscription Paused";
}
```

Maybe there is a way to use a stripe event with a webhook when the trial ends?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems like there may be a solution to this problem via the subscription schedules feature. I'm having trouble getting it all setup though simply because there are not as may examples of this newer feature online.

Comment: I got everything working using the newer subscription schedule feature Stripe has to offer. If you are pausing for an indefinate time then something else would probably be better but if the idea is to pause for a defined amount of time then a schedule is great.

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, you need to disable proration as it is enabled by default when you modify a Subscription: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior

There is no native "pausing" of Stripe Subscription but you can use alternative approaches to get the desired behavior (like switching to a free plan): https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing#pausing-a-subscription

Comment: Am I wrong that disabling proration would charge the full cost of the subscription after unpausing?

Comment: The free plan way seemed to require some kind of event to cancel it at the desired time then create a new subscription with the a trial version of the length left on the original subscription. I am trying to avoid (not looking possible at this point) having anything on the server to handle this process.